# Else not working in if-else if structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Else if structure gives wrong result. I replaced the previous else if and it worked, but this time the below code gave an error.

```js
const gelir_vergisi = {
  gelir: function() {

    matrah = ((document.getElementById("a_sayisi").value) - sgk.vtoplam());
    if (matrah <= (document.getElementById("gelir1").value)) {
      gv1 = (matrah * 15) / 100;
      return gv1;
    } else if ((document.getElementById("gelir1").value) < matrah <= (document.getElementById("gelir2").value)) {
      bir = ((document.getElementById("gelir1").value) * 15) / 100;
      iki = ((matrah - (document.getElementById("gelir1").value)) * 20) / 100;
      gv2 = bir + iki;
      return gv2;
    } else if ((document.getElementById("gelir2").value) < matrah <= (document.getElementById("gelir3").value)) {
      ilk_dilim = ((document.getElementById("gelir1").value) * 15) / 100;
      ikinci_dilim = (((document.getElementById("gelir2").value) - (document.getElementById("gelir1").value)) * 20) / 100;
      ucuncu_dilim = ((matrah - (document.getElementById("gelir2").value)) * 27) / 100;
      gv = ilk_dilim + ikinci_dilim;
      gv3 = gv + ucuncu_dilim;
      return gv3;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: 1. relational operators like `<` when used *with strings* will compare them as *strings*, not as numbers. So `"1" < "2"` is `true`, however `"10" < "2"` is `false`. 2. `x < y <z` does not check if `y` is between `x` and `z`. \

Comment: So how can I write it so that it can compare? Build 1 and 2 work, but build 3 gives an error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the unary plus to cast to number, assuming the fields all contain numbers, otherwise use isNaN to test

Then you can make the whole thing MUCH more readable

I may have entered some brackets wrong, but here is an attempt

NOTE: No need to have else after a return

```js
const gelir_vergisi = {
  gelir: function() {
    let a_sayisi = +document.getElementById("a_sayisi").value;
    let gelir1 = +document.getElementById("gelir1").value;
    let gelir2 = +document.getElementById("gelir2").value;
    let gelir3 = +document.getElementById("gelir3").value;
    const matrah = a_sayisi - sgk.vtoplam();
    if (matrah <= gelir1) return (matrah * 15) / 100;
    if (gelir1 < matrah && matrah <= gelir2) {
      let bir = (gelir1 * 15) / 100;
      let iki = ((matrah - gelir1) * 20) / 100;
      return bir + iki;
    }
    if (gelir2 < matrah && matrah <= gelir3) {
      let ilk_dilim = (gelir1 * 15) / 100;
      let ikinci_dilim = ((gelir2 - gelir1) * 20) / 100;
      let ucuncu_dilim = ((matrah - gelir2) * 27) / 100;
      let gv = ilk_dilim + ikinci_dilim;
      return gv + ucuncu_dilim;
    }
    return 0; // or something else that makes sense
  }
}
```

Comment: early exit: please no `else` after `return`.

Comment: @NinaScholz well spotted. Fixed